# Can a document with a confidentially clause be submitted to a court even if it wasn't subpoenaed?

Tags: contract-law, canada, non-disclosure

If two parties make a contract that contains a confidentiality clause, if one party breaches it can the other still enforce the contract in court?

For example a dispute arises between Party A and Party B. A settlement is reached where Party A agrees to Pay party B some amount of money. The settlement is written and signed. The contract also contains the term "the terms of the agreement are confidential and cannot be disclosed except as required by law." Can party B still start legal action and submit the contract to the court without being in breach of the confidentiality? Can/must/should the full contract be submitted, or only the pertinent parts like the actual terms that were breached? Assume there is no clauses about arbitration or choice of venue.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, if it’s relevant

A private contract does not, in any way, constrain the government. So, if the terms of the contract (or any other document) are relevant, they can be introduced into evidence.